# Android app crashes after minimizing and then opening

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

I restyled the application, without changing the code, everything was fine on the pre-styling version. The application crashes after minimizing and then opening, when initially launched it works fine, crashes only when maximizing after minimizing. The executable code is the same, there is no removal of lessonsContainer (present in one instance in another fragment), and it is not involved in any way in the LessonsNewWordsFragment fragment. Error:

```
5138-5138/soylekz.Droid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: soylekz.Droid, PID: 5138
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a016f (soylekz.Droid:id/lessonsContainer) for fragment LessonsNewWordsFragment{5f3baba #6 id=0x7f0a016f}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1432)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7923)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3359)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:57)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5358)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2078)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

SDK changed to the latest version. When debugging, it goes through the same lines on versions before and after restyling. I don’t understand what could be the matter, in which direction to move.

Add:

**LessonsNewWordsFragment.kt**

```
class LessonsNewWordsFragment : BaseFragment<MainActivity, LessonsNewWordsPresenter>(),
    LessonsNewWordsView,
    LessonsSubtasksAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    lateinit var rvAdapterSubTasks: LessonsSubtasksAdapter

    override val layoutId: Int
        get() = R.layout.fragment_lessons_new_words

    override fun createPresenter(): LessonsNewWordsPresenter = LessonsNewWordsPresenter(this)

    override fun initViews(rootView: View?) {
        val lessonId = arguments?.getInt(ARG_LESSON_ID)!!
        var active_sections_:String = arguments?.getString(ARG_ACTIVE_SECTIONS)!!
        active_sections_ = active_sections_.replace("/", "")
        var active_sections: ActiveSections = Gson().fromJson<ActiveSections>(active_sections_, object : TypeToken<ActiveSections>() {}.type)

        val soundAndTranslationFrag = SoundAndTranslationFragment.newInstance(lessonId)
        val dictionaryCards = LessonCardsFragment.newInstance(lessonId)
        val wordsOnPhoto = LessonPhotosFragment.newInstance(lessonId)
        val exercises = NewWordsExercisesFragment.newInstance(lessonId)

        rvAdapterSubTasks = LessonsSubtasksAdapter()
        rvAdapterSubTasks.onItemClickListener = this
        lessonsNewWordsRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        lessonsNewWordsRv.adapter = rvAdapterSubTasks

        var arrayList = ArrayList<LessonsSubtasksModel>()
        var isChecked = true;
        if (active_sections.word == 1) {
            arrayList.add(LessonsSubtasksModel(getString(R.string.subtaskTvSoundAndTrans), isChecked, soundAndTranslationFrag))
            isChecked = false
        }
        if (active_sections.card == 1) {
            arrayList.add(LessonsSubtasksModel(getString(R.string.subtaskTvDictionaryCards), isChecked, dictionaryCards))
            isChecked = false
        }
        if (active_sections.photo == 1) {
        arrayList.add(LessonsSubtasksModel(getString(R.string.subtaskTvWordsOnPhoto), isChecked, wordsOnPhoto))
            isChecked = false
        }
        if (active_sections.wordexercise == 1) {
            arrayList.add(LessonsSubtasksModel(getString(R.string.subtaskTvExercisesForMem), isChecked, exercises))
            isChecked = false
        }
        rvAdapterSubTasks.setItems(arrayList)

        replaceFragment(R.id.lessonsNewWordsContainer, rvAdapterSubTasks.getItem(0).fragment, null)
        lessonsNewWordsRv.scrollToPosition(0)
    }

    override fun onItemClick(item: Int?, fragment: BaseFragment<*,*>) {
        rvAdapterSubTasks.notifyDataSetChanged()
        lessonsNewWordsRv.scrollToPosition(item!!)
        replaceFragment(R.id.lessonsNewWordsContainer, fragment, null)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val ARG_LESSON_ID = "arg_lesson_id"
        private const val ARG_ACTIVE_SECTIONS = "arg_active_sections"

        fun newInstance(lessonId: Int, active_sections: String): LessonsNewWordsFragment {
            val args = Bundle()
            val fragment = LessonsNewWordsFragment()
            args.putInt(ARG_LESSON_ID, lessonId)
            args.putString(ARG_ACTIVE_SECTIONS, active_sections)
            fragment.setArguments(args)
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<A : BaseActivity<*>, P : BasePresenter> : Fragment(), BaseView {

    protected var presenter: P? = null

    /**
     * You this instead of [android.app.Fragment.getActivity]
     */
    protected lateinit var activity: A

    private var rootView: View? = null

    /**
     * Place your layout resource as return parameter
     *
     * @return resourceId of layout which designed for current fragment
     */
    @get:LayoutRes
    protected abstract val layoutId: Int

    /**
     * You should create an instance of your presenter here. After that you can use [presenter] everywhere in created fragment
     *
     * @return an instance of presenter for created fragment
     */
    protected abstract fun createPresenter(): P

    /**
     * Initialize all views here.
     * This method do the same as [android.app.Fragment.onCreateView]
     *
     * @param rootView already inflated view
     */
    protected abstract fun initViews(rootView: View?)

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        activity = getActivity() as A
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        presenter = createPresenter()
        Utils.changeLang(context!!)
        return inflater?.inflate(layoutId, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = initViews(view)

    /**
     * Replaces existing fragment with allowing state loss
     *
     * @param containerId view where fragment will be replaced
     * @param fragment    new fragment
     * @param tag         for new fragment
     */
    protected fun replaceFragment(@IdRes containerId: Int, fragment: BaseFragment<*, *>, tag: String?) {
        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerId, fragment, tag)?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }

    protected fun replaceFragmentChild(@IdRes containerId: Int, fragment: BaseFragment<*, *>, tag: String?) {
        childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerId, fragment, tag)?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }


    /**
     * Adds fragment into backstack above existing fragment allowing state loss
     *
     * @param containerId view where fragment will be added
     * @param fragment    new fragment
     * @param tag         for new fragment
     */
    protected fun addFragment(@IdRes containerId: Int, fragment: BaseFragment<*, *>, tag: String?) {
        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerId, fragment, tag)?.addToBackStack(tag)
                ?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }

    protected fun addFragmentChild(@IdRes containerId: Int, fragment: BaseFragment<*, *>, tag: String?) {
        childFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(containerId, fragment, tag)?.addToBackStack(tag)
            ?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }

    override fun showProgressView() = activity.showProgressView()

    override fun hideProgressView() = activity.hideProgressView()

}
```

Comment: Can you share your fragment code here

Comment: Added the text of the question with the code, crashes after calling replaceFragment